# Wrong value from array passed by function

Tags: c, googletest

So ive read some other threads that cover this. They make note that its dynmaic so you need to allocate that memory. The issue when I alloce this space then place in my values is that now none of my memory is saved into the array. I was wondering if I'm mallocing wrong or if theres some concept im misunderstanding about arrays and c.

```
//.c file
int *multiply(int m, int n, int *matrix, int *vector,int sizeV){
    int *final = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;

    if(n != sizeV){return NULL;};

    for(i = 0;i < sizeV;i++)
    {
            while(column < n)
            {
                    final[i] += matrix[row] * vector[column];
                    row++;
                    column++;
            }
            column = 0;
            j = 0;
    }
    for(i = 0;i < sizeV;i++)
    {
            printf("\nfinal[%d] = %d\n",i,final[i]);
    }
    return final;
}
```

googletest
    //.googletest file

```
TEST(MultiplyTest, Correct_Result_3x3){
int matrix[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int vector[] = {1,2,3};
int correct[] = {14, 32, 50};   
int *result = multiply(3,3,(int *)matrix, vector,3);

ASSERT_NE(-1, *(result));

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    EXPECT_EQ(correct[i], *(&result[i]));   
}

TEST(MultiplyTest, Correct_Result_2x2){
    int matrix[] = {1,2,4,5};
    int vector[] = {1,2,};
    int correct[] = {5, 14};    
    int *result = multiply(2,2,(int *)matrix, vector,2);

     ASSERT_NE(-1, *(result));

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)                  
        EXPECT_EQ(correct[i], *(result + i));   
    }
```

output
    //output
    [ RUN      ] MultiplyTest.Correct_Result_3x3

```
final[0] = -1656784906

 final[1] = 32620

 final[2] = -1656784870
 src/Matrix-vector_unittests.cpp:15: Failure
 Expected equality of these values:
 correct[i]
 Which is: 14
 *(&result[i])
 Which is: -1656784906
src/Matrix-vector_unittests.cpp:15: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
 correct[i]
 Which is: 32
 *(&result[i])
 Which is: 32620
src/Matrix-vector_unittests.cpp:15: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  correct[i]
  Which is: 50
 *(&result[i])
 Which is: -1656784870
[  FAILED  ] MultiplyTest.Correct_Result_3x3 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] MultiplyTest.Correct_Result_2x2

final[0] = -1656784931

final[1] = 32602

src/Matrix-vector_unittests.cpp:27: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
 correct[i]
 Which is: 5
 *(result + i)
Which is: -1656784931
src/Matrix-vector_unittests.cpp:27: Failure
```

Expected equality of these values:

So again, im not sure what im doing wrong. I dont free the memory currently. Im mainly trying to get these correct values passed over right now and having trouvle with that.

Comment: The only difference between your two codes is a `printf` line. If they behave differently as a result, it suggests *undefined behaviour* somewhere. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: my bad didnt copy over correctly. Ill fix that

Comment: `int *final = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*n)` allocates memory, but does not initialize it. Allocated memory contains garbage. `final[i] += matrix[row] * vector[column]` adds something valid to the garbage.

Comment: I understand that. I should move the print statement. Sorry i lost internet and cant ssh into my stuff. So ill follow up with what happens after that shortly

Comment: I don't think moving the `print()` statement is going to change much;  I believe what user58697 is saying is that after `malloc()`ing the space, you need to initialize it -- to all zeros, I'd say, based on the gist of what that function is doing;  your two main options would be to do it by hand (e.g., loop over the allocated space), or use `memset()`

Comment: ...probably you can leverage the loop you already have;  try adding `final[i] = 0;` just before the `while(column < n)` loop

Comment: regarding: `int *final = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "your error message" );` to output your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)

Comment: in the inner `while()` loop, the variable `row` is incremented for each column.  to multiply the matrix by the array, work with just one row at a time.  As it is, the multiplication of the matrix by the array will not be correct

Comment: regarding: `int *multiply(int m, int n, int *matrix, int *vector,int sizeV){`  would be much better/clearer written as: `int *multiply(int numRows, int numCols, int matrix[ numRows ][ numCols ], int vectorLen, int vector[ vectorLen ] ){`

Comment: thank you guys i appreciate all the help. When i was using memset i wasnt properly addressing the third arguement. I fixed that and it fixed eveything

Comment: thanks but we werent allowed to do a double matrix. Haha that would have been quite a bit easier